# error intGetting the windows user ID from hosted server in silverlight

Tags: silverlight-4.0, iis-5

In my Silverlight application, I am trying to get the logged windows user id in xxx.web project of xxxx.aspx page by using

```
<param name="Initparams"
value="UserName=<%=System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name%>"/>
```

code and am getting the result when running in the local machine. When I deployed it in the server it is getting like **

> NETWORK SERVICE

Can anyone give solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NETWORK SERVICE is probably the Windows identity of the Application Pool for your ASP.NET application. You need to turn off impersonation when using Windows authentication:

```
<!-- Web.config file. -->
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <authentication mode="Windows"/>
    <identity impersonate="true"/>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

You also need to configure your IIS settings to use Integrated Windows authentication. This is all assuming you're on a domain.